# What do I do with the paper check when I make a deposit over the Internet

Tags: united-states, online-banking, check, security

Just opened an account at a credit union that allows me to make deposits over the Internet with my scanner and a Java app.

I assume I need to keep the actual check for at least until the money shows up, but how long should I keep it?

Also, let me know if you have any tips for how you keep them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep the check for 90 days.  That's what most banks advice.  I usually shred the check after that.

The bank has a copy of the scan anyway.  But if it makes you feel better, retain the digital copy as well.

Comment: Make sure to mark it so you remember it was cashed. Presenting an invalid check is a misdemeanor.

Comment: Marking this as the winner since I read the TOS for my credit union.  However I will definitely being doing the envelope thing because that makes me feel good =)

Answer (score 3):

I'd archive the scan, and immediately shred the check. 
Drop the scans into folder by quarter i.e. calendar 3 month groups, and when you start a new folder delete the one that's 2 quarters old.

Comment: Read your TOS. My deposit service wants the paper copy archived for 60 (or was it 90?) days.

Comment: Ok. Envelopes by month. When you start #5, throw out #1 (or empty and relabel it as 5th month.)